# Eliminate subquery to improve query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to rewrite the following subquery as it's used over and over again in a larger query. The DBMS used is Postgres and the table has the following structure `table (id  uuid, seq int, value int)`.

Given a value for id (`id_value`), the query finds all records in "table" where seq < seq of id_value

My naive (slow) solution so far is the following:

```
select * from table
where seq < (select seq from table where id = id_value)
```

```
table
id, seq,  value
a,   1,     12
b,   2,     22
c,   3,     32
x,   4,     43
d,   5,     54
s,   6,     32
a,   7,     54
```

e.g. a query

```
select * from table where seq < (select seq from table where id = 'x')
```

returns

```
a,   1,     12
b,   2,     22
c,   3,     32
```

For testing purposes, I've tried to hardcode the relevant `seq` field and it improves the whole query significantly, but I really don't like to query for `seq` as a two-stage process. Ideally this could happen as part of the query. Any ideas or inspiration would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    seq integer NOT NULL,
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT foo_id_key UNIQUE (id),
    CONSTRAINT foo_seq_key UNIQUE (seq)
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_foo_id
    ON public.foo USING btree
    (id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_foo_seq
    ON public.foo USING btree
    (seq)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Your query selects 50% of the table (in average). That's bound to be slow. Are you sure you need to retrieve as many rows? How big is the table?

Comment: The tables has a few thousand records, not that many are retrieved though.

Comment: That's the output of a simple explain, not from `explain (analyze, buffers)` and formatted text is preferred over images for readability (the same way you formatted your SQL statements)

Comment: Dont think there is much in the SQL you can change. You could code it lots of different ways, most of which would probably have the same result. Maybe a clustered index if there is an ordered list? Hard to know but it sounds like an indexing question to me.

Comment: `id` used to be an int and had thus an implicit order. This is now replaced by two columns, `id` and `seq` which separate identity and order/sequence. The where clause is unfortunately still based on the identity and needs to be translated as `seq` by the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have so many redundant indexes that you are confusing Postgres. Simply defining a column as `primary key` or `unique` is sufficient.  You don't need multiple index declarations.

For what you want to do, this should be optimal:

```
select f.*
from foo f
where f.seq < (select f2.seq from foo f2 where f2.id = :id_value)
```

This should use the index to fetch the `seq` value in the subquery.  Then it should return the appropriate rows.

You could also try:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*, min(seq) filter (where id = :id_value) over () as min_seq
      from foo f
     ) f
where seq < min_seq;
```

However, my suspicion is simply that the query is returning a large number of rows and that is affecting performance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas. Your 2nd query looks very interesting. Could you please explain how (and why?) this works (in particular this part `min(seq) filter (where id = :id_value) over () as min_seq`)? What is the anticipated benefit? Also, the result set contains only a dozen or so rows, so it's not an issue of the payload.

Comment: ok, I think I have an idea what this `min()... filter over()` does. I think it is a way to get the column `seq` which is associated with `:id_value` into the column, next to `id`. The aggregation function is pretty much irrelevant (`max` would also do). That is actually speeding up the query... Thanks so much.